# Discord.py AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'")

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

This bot gives out a role when you click on a reaction in a message, when you delete a reaction, it takes it away, this code worked a year ago and there were no problems, now I run it and get

```py
AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'")
```

I tried to look on the Internet and it seems that I have everything right, I don't understand where I made a mistake, please help

Code:

```py
import discord
from discord import utils
import config

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):

        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji)
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])

                if(len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))

                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)

                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)

            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji)
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: I apologize for spelling mistakes, I don't speak English well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord import utils

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

import config

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # getting the channel object
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # getting the message object
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # we get the object of the user who set the reaction

            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji) # the emoji that the user chose
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

                if(len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))

            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)

            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))

    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # getting the channel object
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # getting the message object
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # we get the object of the user who set the reaction

        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # the emoji that the user chose
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # the object of the selected role (if any)

            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))

        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))


client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client = MyClient(intents = discord.Intents.all())
# RUN
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Traceback quite clear that `member` object is `NoneType` i.e. empty.
This means that

```
member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
```

returns nothing i.e. not getting the data you suppose it to give you.

Comment: How can I fix this? I've already tried everything, now I'll just shoot myself, why did it work exactly a year ago?

Comment: This I don't know, I'm sorry. I'm coming from totally different specialization. I only understand this python error meaning